# v-model is not working in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Actually , this is my problem in my real project doing with `API` . Let me first explain that , I used `axios` for call api data . That will get json array and each array has the same radio value so I append radio value to each array . Although I want to get changed radio value by `v-model` , but it is not working . I outputted `selected` value under radio element . Below I demonstrated like my project code .

```js
var app2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-2',
  data: {
    list: null
  },
  created: function () {
    var json = [{id:1,name:"B"},{id:2,name:"D"}]
    this.list = json
    this.list.forEach(function (v) {
       v.options = [{ text: 'pacageA' , value: 1},{text: 'pagckaeB',value:2}]
       v.selected = null
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-2">
  <div v-for="l,ix in list">
     <div v-for="o in l.options">
      <input type="radio" v-model="l.selected" :name="'test'+ix" :value="o.value">
      </div>
          <h3>{{l.selected}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) one. In order for Vue to know about the new object properties you're adding to your list, you should use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set), eg

```
Vue.set(v, 'options', [{ text: 'pacageA' , value: 1},{text: 'pagckaeB',value:2}])
Vue.set(v, 'selected', null)
```

---

Or, as mentioned below, *"do all the modifications to `json` before assigning it to `this.list`"*.

Comment: Alternatively, do all the modifications to `json` before assigning it to `this.list`.